# Joining versus Union on two MySQL tables with GROUP BY and ORDER BY conditions

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to combine messages and chat tables grouped by threadid and ordered by last_activity.  When I attemted to use UNION I had problems sorting, so I am assuming a join would do better.  I am having trouble with the syntax and was hoping for some guidance. Below are the two selects I am using.  Any help much appreciated.

Select from the messages table:

```
mysql> select threadid, uidto, uidfrom, last_activity, last_message from messages group by threadid order by last_activity DESC;
+----------+-------+---------+---------------------+------------------+
| threadid | uidto | uidfrom | last_activity       | last_message     |
+----------+-------+---------+---------------------+------------------+
|        2 |     2 |       1 | 2013-09-06 22:59:38 | blurred lines... |
|        1 |     9 |       1 | 2013-09-06 22:49:16 | kisses!          |
+----------+-------+---------+---------------------+------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Select from the chat table:

```
mysql> select threadid, uidto, uidfrom, last_activity, last_message from chat group by threadid order by last_activity DESC;
+----------+-------+---------+---------------------+--------------+
| threadid | uidto | uidfrom | last_activity       | last_message |
+----------+-------+---------+---------------------+--------------+
|        2 |     2 |       1 | 2013-09-06 23:03:27 | danke        |
|        1 |     1 |       9 | 2013-09-06 22:30:34 | much         |
+----------+-------+---------+---------------------+--------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: UNION ALL might do the job

Comment: @tim i've tried variations of this: `SELECT chat.threadid, messages.threadid, chat.uidto, messages.uidto, chat.uidfrom, messages.uidfrom, chat.last_activity, messages.last_activity, chat.last_message, messages.last_message FROM messages LEFT JOIN chat GROUP BY threadid ORDER BY last_message;` with no success yet

Comment: @Mihai UNION ALL was still giving me sorting issues. It was complaining about ambiguous tables.

Comment: What are the sorting issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select m.threadid, m.uidto, m.uidfrom, m.last_activity, m.last_message,
c.threadid, c.uidto, c.uidfrom, c.last_activity, c.last_message
FROM messages m
JOIN chat c on m.threadid=c.threadid 
GROUP by threadid ORDER BY last_message


(select m.threadid, m.uidto, m.uidfrom, m.last_activity, m.last_message FROM messages m
UNION ALL
select c.threadid, c.uidto, c.uidfrom, c.last_activity, c.last_message FROM chat c)
GROUP by threadid ORDER BY last_message
```

Comment: Edited,give it a try.

Comment: Ok that seems to work but has a result I didn't realize would happen. Seeing as chat and messages table potentially will have the same threadid, it is grouping them together. Is there anyway to keep them separate via the query or do you think it would be best to just ensure the threadid's are unique between the two tables.

Comment: For a join it would be best to have unique threads,also give that the thread themselves are unique.You should have infact a new table with a unique autoincrement field.

Comment: I'm noticing that if I run the query and there is a threadid 3 in chat and not a 3 in messages, the 3 in chat will not show up.  Is there any way around that to ensure all threadid's are accounted for?

Comment: When I change the JOIN to RIGHT JOIN it seems to see the threadid 3 in the chat table but the columns show NULL.